# Seeking free GIS data for USA equivalent to Swedish General Map?

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial

In Sweden we have "Lantmäteriet" wich is same as "USGS".

"Lantmäteriet" have several datasets like "Road-map","General-map", etc. These data-sets contains boundaries, roads, landcover, contour-lines, lakes,etc. Se the link and the image on that link, thats how the map looks like when I open it in ArcMap. Its only 1 zip file you download, and that file contains all the layers, polylines, polygons, points.

Link to English information PDF about Swedish "General-Map".
https://www.lantmateriet.se/globalassets/kartor-och-geografisk-information/kartor/produktbeskrivningar/eng/e_overshmi.pdf

Does USA have free data-sets that contains the same or similar amount of data as the Swedish General-map and where can I download that data from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many resources that provide general map resources for the United States.

The Census Bureau provides a repository for demographic data and administrative GIS data. In particular, the U.S. Census Bureau releases a series of shapefile data under the TIGER project through their [main website](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html) and through an [FTP directory](ftp://ftp.census.gov/geo/tiger/). TIGER includes administrative boundaries (e.g. states, counties, cities), cartographic boundaries such as shorelines, hydrography within a moderate resolution, roads/highways, and address ranges. This [pdf](ftp://ftp.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2014/2014_TL_Shapefiles_File_Name_Definitions.pdf) is a good example of how it structures each type of information.

---

The USGS has hydrography, land cover classification, digital elevation models (DEM), and land/water boundaries but at a better resolution. They also contain orthographic satellite imagery on their FTP site. You can find more information [here](https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/launch/). It may or may not also have LIDAR data.

---

Lastly, the Bureau of Transportation Statistics includes another avenue for transportation networks through the [National Transportation Atlas Database](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/publications/national_transportation_atlas_database/index.html).

---

I hope this information was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But is there somewhere that I can download a "complete map" for a county or city that contains all data like roads, land cover, houses, i mean without downloading single files?